# How to sort a list of strings by highest number

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings which is made by combining two separate lists to make a string. The student list is :

`['me: 9', 'him: 7', 'you: 9', 'her: 8']` .

How do I sort it on highest numerical value, i.e.

`['me: 9', 'you: 9', 'her: 8','him: 7']`

```
student_list = []
for x, y in zip(files, scores):
    student_result = (x + ": " + y)
    student_list.append(student_result)
```

This is the code to combine the two lists; I'm not sure whether this needs changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
student_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse=True)

print(student_list)
```

or if you don't want to change the original list:

```
sorted_student_list = sorted(student_list, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse=True)

print(sorted_student_list)
```

Then again, it probably makes more sense to combine the lists into a list of tuples:

```
student_list = []
for x, y in zip(files, scores):
    student_result = (x, int(y))
    student_list.append(student_result)

print(student_list)
```

and then use `key=lambda x: x[1]` in your `sort`/`sorted` function.

Comment: this works, but it prints as [('me', 9), ('you', 9), ('her', 8), ('him', 7)]. How do I make print as ['me: 9', 'you: 9', 'her: 8','him: 7'], i.e. one combined string

Comment: You already had it as one string - in that case ignore the second half of my answer starting from "Then again..."

Comment: use the first key `key=lambda x: int(x[-1])`